# lattice xyplot - add a regression line to part of the data

Tags: r, line, lattice

I have a question about xyplot from lattice library in R.

Here is the example of the data:

```
set.seed(4)
mydata <- data.frame(x.data = rnorm(50),
                 y.data = rnorm(50),
                 type = rep(c("A","B"), 50))
head(mydata)

mod <- lm(x.data ~ y.data*type, data= mydata)
summary(mod)

xyplot(y.data + fitted(mod) ~ x.data, groups= type, data= mydata, auto.key=F)
```

How would it be possible to add a regression line only to type A data and only in the fitted(mod) part of the plot. Is it possible to have the regression line only from the min to max value?

I hoped that the result could look somethnig like this:
[image]

Thank you for the help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

set.seed(4)
mydata <- data.frame(x.data = rnorm(50),
                     y.data = rnorm(50),
                     type = rep(c("A","B"), 50))
head(mydata)

mod <- lm(x.data ~ y.data*type, data= mydata)
p1 <- predict(mod, newdata = data.frame(y.data = range(mydata$y.data), type = "A"))

xyplot(y.data + fitted(mod) ~ x.data, groups= type, data= mydata, auto.key=F) +
  layer(panel.lines(range(mydata$x.data), p1, col = "black", lty = 1), rows = 1, columns = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Thank you Pascal. One more question - would it be possible to limit the line only on this part where the data are available - from xmin to xmax?

Comment: Thank you for this quick replay!